# How to use hugepages with tmpfs

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel

I need to use tmpfs with hugepages and what I tried is : `sudo mount -t ramfs -osize=6G,mode=1777,id=$ID,huge=always tmpfs memory_path`

With `huge=always` but there is no different result from before

Is there something that I've missed? Can someone explain please?

Comment: "there is no different result from before" - What kind of "difference" you expect when use  `huge=always` parameter? According to [man 5 tmpfs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html), that value is meant just an **attempt** to use huge pages every time a page is requested.

Comment: I guessed that if I put that parameter, the number of huge pages used would have increased. But nothing happened

Comment: @Tsyvarev Does you mean that we need to create a hugepage on the system before creating a file in that tmpfs? `sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=2048`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ramfs and tmps are two similar, but different file systems. ramfs doesn't support the parameter `huge=always`, so you can't notice any difference. Try this one:

```bash
sudo mount -t tmpfs -osize=6G,mode=1777,huge=always tmpfs memory_path
```